# display one row of while loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm making a quiz. I'm getting all the questions on one page, but I don't want that. I only want the first question. After the button is clicked, then i want the second question. How can I accomplish this? Here's my code:

```
$qry=mysql_query("select `id`,`question` from `paper_details` where `paper_id`='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    $num_rw= mysql_num_rows($qry);
    while($f=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
    { 
        $q2=mysql_query("select `id`,`que`,`unique_id`,`image` from `que_master` where `id`='".$f['question']."'") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $f2=mysql_fetch_row($q2); 
        $i=$pid;?>
 <table width="98%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4" class="form_border" id="form_table">
  <tr>
   <th width="3%" rowspan="2" align="left" valign="top" class="form_label"></th>
   <th width="5%" height="27" align="left" valign="top" class="form_label">Que<?php echo $i;?> : </th>
   <th width="92%" align="left" valign="top" class="form_label"> <?php echo $f2[1]; if($f2[3]!=""){?>
   <img src="admin/que_image/<?php echo $f2[3];?>" border="noborder" width="20px" height="20px"/><?php }?>
    <input type="hidden" id="que_id" name="que_id" value="<?php echo $f2[0];?>"/>
   </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th height="78" align="left" valign="top" class="form_label">Ans : </th>
   <td align="left" valign="top"  style="line-height:2.0em;">
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="pid" name="pid" value="<?php echo $pid+1;?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="num_raw" name="num_raw" value="<?php echo $num_rw;?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="time" name="time" value="<?php echo $time;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="que_id" name="que_id" value="<?php echo $f2[0];?>" />
  <?php 

        $q3=mysql_query("select `id`,`ans`,`ans_img` from `ans_master` where `unique_id`='$f2[2]'") or die(mysql_error()); 

        while($f3=mysql_fetch_row($q3)){ 
        ?>
                <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $f3[0]; ?>" name="ans" id="ans"><?php echo $f3[1]; ?><?php if($f3[2]!=""){?>
                   <img src="admin/ans_image/"<?php echo $f3[2];?>" border="noborder" width="20px" height="20px"/>

        <?php   }
                }}
            ?>
 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th height="33" align="left" valign="middle" class="form_label">&nbsp;</th>
   <th colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle" class="form_label">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Next >" />
```

Please help me.

Comment: you have to handle this using javascript

Comment: @Populus - Mmm, not necessarily. Handling it without a full page refresh? Then yes, JavaScript with a dose of AJAX will be needed. I think that [`LIMIT` and `OFFSET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#idm47039154543520) will be of use database-side though.

Comment: it's easier with javascript, so you can just handle showing and hiding questions, then submit everything in one go, instead of having to save the answers to all the questions until he finally submits the paper.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have a single-page application to run your quiz.
For this purpose, you could use ajax requests with jquery.

Or else, you can make a separate page for each question.